# load Wavefront Object in iphone with OpenGl?

Tags: opengl

I have to load a wavefront created Object in a iphone with the openGL. i had get this link for the Loading of Wavefront object in iphone sdk.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/start-of-wavefront-obj-file-loader.html

http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wavefront_obj_files_and_learning

I had used the sample code given in this link but the problem is that my object is not loaded.

Is there any limitation with the loading of big object in Iphone?

If you have link or solution than please help me over this problem .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only correct answer is to tell you wavefront and openGL have nothing to do with eachother, They don't know about eachother, and you're providing the glue. So, you've either got a problem with your wavefront loading code, or you've got a problem on the opengl side.

Which doesn't really help you :)

First, I would recommend you check if everything on  the gl side is working .Try to make a small object manually in code, maybe one triangle. Then try to make a big one.

If that is working, try the wavefront side. Make a single triangle. If that works, try and make the geometry complexer until it works.

Sorry, but your issue is way to fuzzy to give a good answer.